# How to perform UrlFetchApp.fetch while sending a specific cookie - google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, cookies, urlfetch

I am trying to retrieve in a google application script the html content of a website to extract some piece of information.

First I tried to use:
`var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(modelUrl,opt).getContentText();`

==> When I displayed the response with `Logger.log(page)` I noticed the website asking for cookies use and so I could not get the desired response.

So I analysed in firefox the cookies for this website and noticed that I should have a cookie named `displd` whose content is `0` to access the site content.

My question is therefore how can I perform the UrlFetchApp operation while sending this specific cookie for it to work?
Would you have a code example for me?

EDIT: tried the refered approach but when I do I get absolutely nothing as a result so maybe it does not provide a way to send cookie but rather try to log in?
Sincerely

Comment: Regarding your edit,  you need to provide [mcve]. Better to ask a new question with mcve.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. What is mcve?

Comment: Read the above link fully. You'll know  what mcve is